# Number of walks in a looped Vertex (path)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If there is a vertex, V1. And V1 has a loop around itself. Why are there 4 walks around the loop?

Apologies, an error comes up when i attach an image, so I've got to describe the image with words.

Edit: I can only envision 2 walks. One walk going clockwise around the loop and the other anti-clockwise.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Paste the link, I'll add the picture. What you are trying to say is incomprehensible right now.

Comment: It is a cropped image from my online pdf notebook. So not sure how that works. But the graph is basically a vertex with a loop around itself.

Comment: Is it a directed graph? If not, the orientation of the walk (clockwise or anticlockwise) has no significance.

Comment: In the case of an undirected graph composed of a single vertex $v_1$ with a self-loop $e$, there could be two walks at best: $v_1$ and $v_1,e,v_1$. Maybe you use a different definition of walk?

Comment: correct, it is an un-directed graph. The book quotes "there are 4 walks twice around the loop".

Comment: The definition of walk that I use is _an alternating sequence of vertices and edges, beginning and ending with a vertex such that each edge appears atmost once and between its end vertices_.